# Create a validation rule to check that a contact is in the zip code of its account

Tags: validation-rule, trailhead, developer

I think i misunderstood validation rules, so i answered the following challenge creating a validation rule that only applies if the insertion is different for what i write in the rule:

```
AND(ISBLANK( Account.Id ),
OR( MailingPostalCode = Account.ShippingPostalCode ))
```

I mean, if the insertion/update is correct, then do it, else display error message.

The challenge has **succeeded**.

My **question** is, am i wrong or i should write in the validation rule the conditions where **should'nt** be accepted?

Here is the [challenge](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules?trail_id=force_com_dev_beginner&trailmix_creator_id=hcerverapanella&trailmix_id=trailheads-basicos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the challenge

> - A contact with a MailingPostalCode that has an account and does not match the 
>     associated Account ShippingPostalCode should return with a validation error and 
>     not be saved.
> - The validation rule should ONLY apply to contact records with an associated 
>     account. Contact records with no associated parent account can be added with any 
>     MailingPostalCode value. (Hint: you can use the ISBLANK function for this check)

the correct approach will be as follows:

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Account.Id)) 
, NOT(ISBLANK(MailingPostalCode)) 
, NOT(ISBLANK(Account.ShippingPostalCode))
, (MailingPostalCode != Account.ShippingPostalCode)
)
```

Since, you need to check all the blank entries for Account's `Id`, `ShippingPostalCode` and Contact's `MailingPostalCode` and then validate if Contact's `MailingPostalCode != Account.ShippingPostalCode`

Answer (score 1):

The correct validation rule for the mentioned challenge is

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK( AccountId )),
    MailingPostalCode  <>  Account.ShippingPostalCode
)
```

Validation rule should check for the conditions that should'nt be accepted.